# "Degree of Proximity" or "Proximity of Blood" or "Relation Proximity"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, expression-choice, interpersonal-relations

I'm translating a civil record to English, which has a table of information about a family registry. One of the titles is "*Degree of Proximity*", however I'm not sure which of the expressions suits the best in this context.

The items below that title in the column are: "*himself, wife, son, daughter*".

Wikipedia has an entry for *[Proximity of blood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_of_blood)*, and Google returns only 306,000 results for "*degree of proximity*" within the double quotes, which is not many.

What's the appropriate title I should use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use 'Family relationship'?

[Free Dictionary Definition:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/family+relationship)

> **Noun**  1.  family relationship - (anthropology) relatedness or connection by blood or marriage or adoption

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the title was shortened, and the phrase should be understood as "***Degree of Proximity (of blood)***"

Or it could be that "of blood" was dropped in order to show that "non-blood" -- and maybe non-traditional -- relations are to be included. In that case, you might coin something like ***degree of familial proximity***.